# How to make a .exe from python script with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package up my python file into an .exe file using pyinstaller.

I managed to install pyinstaller with pip but when trying to use pipinstaller in a command window it wouldn't work. I found online to use `python -m PyInstaller` instead which then worked. But after using cd to change the directory and then doing `python -m PyInstaller filename.py` it would always give a list of errors saying `1920, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'The file cannot be accessed by the system.'`.

I'm using windows 10, python 3.8.3 and the newest version of pip but I couldn't find a soloution. I ran command prompt as an operator but it still wouldn't help.

Any soloutions?

Comment: Did you install python from the windows store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the path you've installed your python

if you don't know where you installed python, in the console type 'where python'

```
> where python
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
```

then go to the path

next, go to 'Scripts' folder

```
cd Scripts
```

in the Scripts folder, make sure there is pyinstaller.exe file there

if you find pyinstaller.exe in this folder, you are sure pyinstaller is installed on your system, then

```
> pyinstaller {path to the main.py}
```

there is two useful switch for pyinstaller

1. --onefile         >>  your project packaged into ONE file
2. --noconsole       >>  no console appear when your app is running

For eg:

> pyinstaller d:\myapp\main.py --onefile

You can find your final dot.exe file in the 'dist' folder in 'Scripts' folder

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same question, so I uninstall python which is installed from windows appstore, and reinstall it from the website, and it works fine now, hope it help

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try another one after failing to use pyinstaller. I used py2exe and shortly after trying managed to convert it into an .exe file along with moving my files inside of where my python was stored.