# No error while adding icon to EXE file with Pyinstaller Spec,still icon is not showing

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, publishing

I am new to pyinstaller.
While I was compiling my exe file I got no error.
[image: Output at compilation time]

I have added logo path to spec file.

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      Tree('exp','exp'),
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='Screen2text',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      upx_exclude=[],
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=False,
      icon=r'D:\backup\logo.ico')
```

But after compiling,I can't see that logo on my exe file.Size of my logo file is 423KB.
Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the icon has changed, but Windows File Explorer cashed the old icon and not show the new one. just rename the file, File explorer will update the icon and you will sure the new icon has set or no. you can check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62122077/how-to-make-a-exe-from-python-script-with-pyinstaller/62241490#62241490

Comment: Thanks I just found...This is the case...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually the icon has changed, but the Windows `File Explorer` cached the old icon and does not display the new one.
**Things to do:**
Just rename the file, File explorer will update the icon and you will sure the new icon has set or not.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes...This was the case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, in the console oin the path o your project:

**if you want the executable in one file(slower start)**:
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon="your_icon_file".ico "your_python_script".py

**if you want the executable in one folder(faster start)**:
pyinstaller.exe --onedir --windowed --icon="your_icon_file".ico "your_python_script".py

this wil create a folder call "dist" where your .exe will be,

**pd**: whith the --onedir command you will see all your dependencies in that folder, if you have a simple script you can use the first option.